# How to activate Android debugging mode

Tags: settings, usb-debugging

I've recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy 5 from Android 2.1 to 2.2 and I can't find Android debugging mode in the settings. I need to root my phone.

Answer (score 13):

It's usually located in

> Settings > Applications > Development

Of course, you could just perform a quick and easy root by installing Universal Androot as detailed here - http://androidadvices.com/root-unroot-samsung-galaxy-5-i5500-easy-tutorial/2/#.UF3Qi1H1pjc